# How to bring my secondary dialog window to the top when the CDialog-based app starts?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I've coded an MFC `CDialog` based application. In normal circumstances it starts up by displaying a `CDialog` window from the `InitInstance` handler as such:

```
CMyDialog dlg;
INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
```

But for the first time this app runs I need to display another dialog from within `CMyDialog::OnInitDialog` before the main dialog is on the screen. So I do a similar thing:

```
CIntroDialog idlg(this);
idlg.DoModal();
```

But the issue with this approach is that my second `CIntroDialog` is not displayed in the foreground. So I attempted to fix this by calling the following from within `CIntroDialog::OnInitDialog`:

```
    this->SetForegroundWindow();
    this->BringWindowToTop();
```

but it didn't do anything.

I then tried calling `::AllowSetForegroundWindow(ASFW_ANY);` from `InitInstance` for the app, and that didn't do anything either.

Any idea how to bring that second dialog to the foreground when the app starts?

PS. Due to the structure of this app, I need to call `CIntroDialog::DoModal` from within `CMyDialog::OnInitDialog` to prevent an extensive rewrite.

Comment: Not sure, but  calling `CIntroDialog::DoModal` from an `OnInitDialog` function may be a bad idea.

Comment: Surprising, a small test here doing that works fine. I'd try seeing if commenting-out code in either or both `OnInitDialog`s has an effect. If you don't come right, you could set a timer in `CMyDialog::OnInitDialog` to go off in half a second or something, and in the timer handler invoke `CIntroDialog`.

Comment: Do you require any user interaction in the Intro dialog, or, is it simply to display information?

Comment: Yes, there's some user interaction in the Intro dialog.

Comment: Just a hunch, make sure your CIntroDialog resource Visible property is set to TRUE.  I always get burned on that one.

Comment: Are you calling CIntroDialog's DoModal AFTER the chainback to CDialog::OnInitDialog in CMyDialog::OnInitDialog?

Answer (score 3):

Have you consider making use of `InitInstance` for this in the app class?

```
BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance()
{
    AfxEnableControlContainer();

    // Standard initialization
    // If you are not using these features and wish to reduce the size
    //  of your final executable, you should remove from the following
    //  the specific initialization routines you do not need.

    CMyDlg dlg;
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
    if (nResponse == IDOK)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with OK
    }
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with Cancel
    }

    // Since the dialog has been closed, return FALSE so that we exit the
    //  application, rather than start the application's message pump.
    return FALSE;
}
```

I have cut some of the default implementation out, but you see this bit:

```
CMyDlg dlg;
m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
if (nResponse == IDOK)
{
    // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
    //  dismissed with OK
}
else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
{
    // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
    //  dismissed with Cancel
}
```

There is nothing stopping you doing something like:

```
CMyDlg2 dlg2;

if(dlg2.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    CMyDlg dlg;
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
    if (nResponse == IDOK)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with OK
    }
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with Cancel
    }
}
else
{
    // Handle IDCANCEL
}
```

I admit I have not tested the above code, but I can't see why you can't execute the first dialogue and then the second dialogue.

Comment: Like I mentioned above: _"Due to the structure of this app, I need to call CIntroDialog::DoModal from within CMyDialog::OnInitDialog to prevent an extensive rewrite."_