# MFC dialog window does not appear

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2017

I am just learning to create MFC applications in visual studio 2017. I have made a new *default* project of MFC dialog based application. After completing the steps of MFC application wizard, visual studio shows up to this:

[image: State].

At this point I have not changed any of the code or settings.

Now how do I get the dialog window as shown in:

[image: here]

I have tried rebuilding the solution, but it does not work.

Comment: I guess you should select it in `Solution explorer` window.

Comment: "I am just learning to create MFC applications"  - do you have any specific reason for doing this? Otherwise I would suggest not - MFC is really dead technology.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I am trying to create a GUI for a c++ app, and I searched a bit and found it. What are some better options?

Comment: Not using C++ to create GUI apps, or using better frameworks than MFC, such as Qt.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I am using c++ because its a part of a project. I need to create a dictionary that performs word prediction, neighbor search, and displays meaning.

Comment: @VTT Can you elaborate a bit more? Thanks

Comment: It has been a while since I've used it, but typically you need to double-click on item in solution explorer to open UI editor. Maybe you should open resource file `MFCApplication2.rc` and then select a dialog in `Resource view` window.

Comment: What happens when you click "Local Windows Debugger"? Your application starts in this file: `"CMFCApplication2.cpp"` You can put a break point in `InitInstance` to follow the steps.

Comment: And you hit `F5` to run the project. Or, `Debug->Start Debugging` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure if I am answering correctly.

- Click on the **View** menu.
- Then click on **Other Views**.
- Now click **Resource View**

[image: Resource View]

Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

Now you have the **Resource View**:

[image: Resource View Tab]

If you click that you see all resources:

[image: Resource Editor]

That is how you get to your dialogues.

If you have created a **secondary** dialog and you want that to start instead of the default, then look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035296/how-to-bring-my-secondary-dialog-window-to-the-top-when-the-cdialog-based-app-st/41041614#41041614) about using **InitInstance**.

Comment: Alternatively just double-click the .rc file in Solution Explorer which will automatically open the resource view.